# math - how to alter the values of function as if they were rotated by specified angle

Tags: math, rotation

I was wondering if there is a mathematical way (sure there is one!) to rotate curve made by polynomial equation.

For example, I have a polynomial `x^3 + 2x^2 + 1 = 0` and if I draw a curve from that polynomial it is parallel to x-axis (more or less - it's a curve :). So I have `x` values and `y` values corresponding to `x` values because `y = f(x)`. So after calculating all values for some range I would have 2D array where key number is `x` and value is `y`.
How should I transform `x`'s and `y`'s to get the values as if all coordinates system would be moved by (for example) 10 degrees clockwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply [rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix).
That is, for each `(x, y)`, compute

```
new_x = x * cos(theta) - y * sin(theta);
new_y = x * sin(theta) + y * cos(theta);
```

In your example (rotate by 10 degrees clockwise), `theta` equals to -10 degrees. You may need to convert it into radians.